# Не могу получить данные из таблицы posgresql

Tags: postgresql

Не могу получить данные из таблицы из под обычного пользователя. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Ну вот что получилось. Почему-то тоже самое, чёт ничего не понимаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grant usage on schema public to simple_user;
```

Отобрали права на схему вы сами предварительно. `usage` на схему `public` выдан по-умолчанию всем. Внимательнее с `revoke` и не надо упускать такие детали в вопросе.

---

Сам текст ошибки о том, что отсутствует такой `relation` вместо более ожидаемого сообщении об отсутствии прав происходит от того, что вы указали `from department`, а не `from schema_name.table_name`. Потому в рассмотрение берётся `search_path`, который проверяет существование и права доступа к указанным схемам, не генерируя ошибку доступа. Таким образом после просмотра всех указанных в `search_path` схемах получается ответ, что такого объекта нет. Но возможно что нет прав на схему.

Comment: Спасибо большое.